# How do you do a custom filter with special character?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am using react bootstrap table, and have a column named Order Date.  I would like to have a filter that user can type in a date (for example: 03/2019) to get all the products ordered in March 2019.
So my column definition looks like this:

```
 dataField: 'orderDate',
 text: 'Order Date',
 sort: true,
 headerStyle: {fontSize: '12px', whiteSpace:'nowrap'},
 filter: textFilter({placeholder:'mm/yyyy'})
```

It works great until the "/".  I can search 03, and returns all products ordered in March, but as soon as I entered the slash, no results were rendered. If I search 032019, it does not return anything either.

I tried the dateFilter, but I don't want users to have to scroll through the calendar. They like the textFilter-like simplicity.

Is there a way to make the slash work?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a regex pattern then filter.

```js
    const pattern = new RegExp('11/2012', 'gi');

    const dates = ['02/2010', '10/2011', '11/2012'];
    
    console.log(dates.filter(date => pattern.test(date)));
```